# Why can't Visual Studio find my WPF InitializeComponent method?

Tags: wpf

This is very strange.

I have an [XAML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extensible_Application_Markup_Language) file that looks as follows...

```
<Window
    x:Name="window"
    x:Class="ix.Production.Title"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="Title" Height="768" Width="1024"
    Loaded="window_Loaded">

    <Window.Resources>
   etc...
```

And my code-beside that looks as follows...

```
using System;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Media.Animation;
using System.Threading;

namespace ix.Production
{
    public partial class Title : Window
    {
        public Title()
        {
           InitializeComponent();
        }
    ....
```

This code refuses to compile because Visual Studio insists that the InitializeComponent "does not exist in the current context."

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Arg, silly typo from my side (I have two similar projects). The class namespace is actually correct, but I still get the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like this was a kink in Visual Studio 2008.

If I create a new file (i.e. Title2), copy/paste the code and XAML, then change all 'Title' to 'Title2', everything works fine again.

Answer (score 56):

One case I have seen this happening in when you copy paste an XAML control/window, etc.
The InitializeComponent method exists in a corresponding .g.cs file that is automatically generated. In my case, after copy paste, **Build Action** for the XAML (in Properties window) was changed to "Resource". I **changed it to "Page"**, and it started working fine.

I hope this helps.

The thread which helped me with this was *[The name 'InitializeComponent' does not exist...](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/2f755d30-bd8c-4f9b-b36a-9cb56bea15cd/the-name-initializecomponent-does-not-exist?forum=wpf)*.

Comment: I have this problem a lot when copying and pasting, great to know to check this.

Comment: Yap, just had this issue when copying XAML files between projects

Comment: +1 Mine got changed to `CodeAnalysisDictionary` after a Cut & Paste operation... nice one Microsoft! All fixed after setting it back to `Page`. Many thanks gp.

Comment: Mine was changed to `EntityDeploy`. Really weird that it sort of randomly changed to another build action. + 1

Comment: When copy/pasting code, be careful to **ensure namespaces and classes agree with code-behind**. This is the mistake I had made.

Comment: changing the build to something else and back to Page worked in my case (was already marked as 'Page')....

Comment: @dba Exactly what I observed, too. Hard to find such errors that don't exist.

Comment: @dba this should be its own answer. This is what finally solved my issue

Answer (score 38):

Your XAML says:

```
x:Class="ix.Production.Title"
```

while the actual class is `ix.Outage.Title`. Either change the XAML declaration or move the class to the `ix.Production` namespace.

Answer (score 18):

So simple, but so easy to overlook: `MainWindow`'s `x:Class` was set to "`MainWindow`", when it should have been set to `namespace.MainWindow` (`x:Class="namespace.MainWindow"`). If this is not done, then the `MainWindow.g.xaml` file will not include a namespace block, and the call to `InitializeComponent()` in `MainWindow`'s constructor will not work.

Although this obviously isn't a solution to willem's problem, I posted it here because there are so many other solutions listed. Hopefully this will help someone else who stumbles on this post when trying to fix their problem.

Answer (score 9):

Your namespaces don't match:

```
x:Class="ix.Production.Title"
namespace ix.Outage { ...
```

Comment: In order to check correct namespace you can go to Project -> Properties -> AssemplyInfo.cs and look for the namespace name in the `XmlnsDefinition`. If you forgot to add the `XmlnsDefinition` then it might be a good idea to do so.

Answer (score 2):

I usually get this problem when renaming custom control classes, or, as in your case, changing the name of the class's namespace. If you don't use Visual Studio's refactoring, then you have to manually change the names in both XAML and C# files.

Refactoring is only good when you just rename the class, for namespace rename, you have to do it manually.

For `InitializeComponent`, look in `[Project Folder]\obj\Debug\<class_name.g.cs>`.

Comment: Or just delete the entire \obj file and let Visual Studio rebuild it

Comment: Or that, I was going for a complete answer :)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with a Visual Studio 2010 sample project that I manually reverted to Visual Studio 2008. I found I had forgotten to set the Target Framework of the project to .NET Framework 3.5. It was empty in the project reverted to Visual Studio 2008, initially set to 4.0 in the original Visual Studio 2010 project.

To set Target Framework of a project, go to project properties, access the first tab called *Application*, and select .NET Framework 3.5 in the Target Framework dropdown.

Of course, I'd prefer Visual Studio giving me an error or at least a warning that I had not set my Target Framework, but hey, that's part of developing in Visual Studio, I guess.

[image: Visual Studio 2008 WPF project properties]

Answer (score 1):

I become unable to find InitializeComponent, and other XAML-related UI bits from the code behind the moment I add my PCL (which contains my data classes) into the solution.

:|

But if I remove the PCL one .. it can be found again.

Regardless, whether its found or not - I can still compile. I just can't autocomplete when i type code.

Maybe you have a PCL project in your solution?
(I don't know how to fix this yet)

Answer (score 0):

Your class is partial, so you should have another file that contains some other parts of your Title class (the InitializeComponent method for instance).
Try to find that file, and see if the namespace in that file, is equal to the namespace of the file which contains the other parts of your class.

Comment: It says partial... but I wonder if the actual InitializeComponent is not generated somewhere by WPF? I'm not sure. Haven't been able to find it.

Answer (score 0):

I was strugling with the same issue here. What I did was to delete ALL the created files unde the debug folder, then rebuild the solution.

Regards,
Petrus

Answer (score 0):

I had come across the same problem when i got a project sample from msdn. the issue was it was a 4.0 project and i did not have the 4.0 in my system, couple of referenced dlls were missing(system.xaml and another one) removed them. tried to compile, would always throw the initializecomponent method not found. went into the project properties changed the target framework to 3.5 and it is not complaining anymore.

Answer (score 0):

FWIW, I hit the same problem today after migration of a Visual Studio 2008 solution to Visual Studio 2010. It appears that the migration goofed and the projects lost their `Target Framework` (in Project Properties): The setting is now empty!?

Setting `.NET Framework 3.5` solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me because Visual Studio sets the "Build action" to some random *action* when you copy/paste or move an XAML file from one project to another within a solution.

Solution: Make sure your "Build action" is set to page for you XAML.

I hope this helps if it's the same case for you.

Answer (score 0):

When namespaces are all correct changing the target platform from x86 to x64 or vice versa and rebuilding the  project often does the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the csproj file. In my case, I had very strange (automatically added) include and remove instructions in it. Removing them solved the problem.

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <Page Remove="Views\DashboardView.xaml" />
    <Page Remove="Views\MainWindow.xaml" />
    <Page Remove="Views\SettingsView.xaml" />
    <Page Remove="Views\SidebarView.xaml" />
    <Page Remove="Views\SubSettingsView.xaml" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <None Include="Views\DashboardView.xaml">
      <Generator>MSBuild:Compile</Generator>
    </None>
    <None Include="Views\MainWindow.xaml">
      <Generator>MSBuild:Compile</Generator>
    </None>
    <None Include="Views\SettingsView.xaml">
      <Generator>MSBuild:Compile</Generator>
    </None>
    <None Include="Views\SidebarView.xaml">
      <Generator>MSBuild:Compile</Generator>
    </None>
    <None Include="Views\SubSettingsView.xaml">
      <Generator>MSBuild:Compile</Generator>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>
```